# In a component Angular 2, how to get children without knowing the kind of object?

Tags: angular, children

In my **parent-component**, I can put in his content two types of component : **child-component-A** and **child-component-B**... so, we can have several possibilities :

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component-A></child-component-A>
  <child-component-A></child-component-A>
</parent-component>
```

or/and

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component-B></child-component-B>
  <child-component-B></child-component-B>
</parent-component>
```

or/and

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component-A></child-component-A>
  <child-component-B></child-component-B>
</parent-component>
```

How can I get children in **parent.component.ts** using something like **@content-children** ?

Comment: There is no way. A shared service might work better to communicate between such components.

Comment: you can try with element reference and then find it's child

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `@ContentChild()` or `@ContentChildren()` if you don't know the class of the component you are targetting, But you can use a shared service to communicate between child and parent or you can inject parent in child:

### Shared Service approach:

#### SharedService

```js
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    private childrenEvents = new ReplaySubject < ["add" | "remove", ChildA | ChildB] > ();
    children: Observable < [ChildA | ChildB] > 

    constructor() {
        let output: [ChildA | ChildB]=[];
        this.children = Observable.merge(
            this.childrenEvents.filter(([action, child]) => action === "add").do(([action, child]) => output = output.concat(child)),
            this.childrenEvents.filter(([action, child]) => action === "remove").do(([action, child]) => output = output.filter(item => item !== child))
        ).map(() => output).publishBehavior([]);
        this.children.connect();

    }

    addChild(child: ChildA | ChildB) {
        this.childrenEvents.next(["add", child]);
    }

    removeChild(child: ChildA | childB) {
        this.childrenEvents.next(["remove", child]);
    }


}
```

#### Parent

```js
@Component({
    template: "<ng-content></ng-content>",
    selector: "parent"
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private sub: Subscription;
    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.sharedService.children.subscribe(children => {
            console.log(children)
        })
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

#### ChildA / ChildB

There is just ChildA here, but it's the same behavior for ChildB.

```js
@Component({
    template: "child a component",
    selector: "child-a"
})
export class ChildA implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private sub: Subscription;
    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
       this.sharedService.addChild(this);
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sharedService.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

### Inject Parent into Child

You can avoid using a service by just injecting the ParentComponent in the children.

#### Parent

```js
@Component({
    template: "<ng-content></ng-content>",
    selector: "parent"
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy{

    private childrenEvents = new ReplaySubject < ["add" | "remove", ChildA | ChildB] > ();
    children: Observable < [ChildA | ChildB] > 

    constructor() {
            let output: [ChildA | ChildB]=[];
            this.children = Observable.merge(
                this.childrenEvents.filter(([action, child]) => action === "add").do(([action, child]) => output = output.concat(child)),
                this.childrenEvents.filter(([action, child]) => action === "remove").do(([action, child]) => output = output.filter(item => item !== child))
            ).map(() => output).publishBehavior([]);
            this.children.connect();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.sharedService.children.subscribe(children => {
            console.log(children);
        })
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    addChild(child: ChildA | ChildB) {
        this.childrenEvents.next(["add", child]);
    }

    removeChild(child: ChildA | childB) {
        this.childrenEvents.next(["remove", child]);
    }

}
```

#### ChildA / ChildB

```js
@Component({
    template: "child a component",
    selector: "child-a"
})
export class ChildA implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private sub: Subscription;
    constructor(private parent: ParentComponent) {}
    ngOnInit() {
       this.parent.addChild(this);
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

- If you want to be able to use `ChildA` or `ChildB` without the `Parent` component, you just need to mark this parameter as optional for the injector:

  ```js
  export class ChildA {
      constructor(@Optional() private parent: ParentComponent) {}
  }
  ```
- You might experience some cyclic dependencies `SharedService` needs `ChildA` and `ChildA` needs `SharedService`. You can avoid that by creating an interface that will be used in the service or parent component (depending on the approach you choose) for representing the `ChildA`/`ChildB` class or declare those classes in the same file / module.
- I used `ChildA|ChildB` types for brievity, if `ChildA` and `ChildB` have a common ancestor, or both implement an interface eg:`IChild` or `AbstractChild`, it would be better to use that `AbstractChild` or `Ichild` type instead.